# Can I connect my Android to my laptop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have a Motorola Moto E running kitkat 4.4.4. Is there any way to link my phone to my laptop (Windows 8) and control the phone from there? Such as downloading apps to the phone via usb connection from the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to control your phone using your laptop.
GO through [this](http://vysor.io/) link and download Vysor to your laptop as well as phone.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remote control device? If that so, than you can use app "teamviewer" it requires internet connection or "air droid" air droid support control via usb if I remember right. Or maybe you dont have wifi so you want to use PC internet because you don't have wifi, than you can use reverse usb tethering here is how to http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494 . Im not sure you could do remote control via air droid and reverse tether if you wanted to. Also you can install apps via pc without touching phone, to do that you have to login to google on PC with same account which is used on Android to connect to google. Just go to google play in any browser and choose app you want to install and it will offer you list of devices connected to that google account, so choose device and confirm, just one thing app will not install on the phone until it's connected to internet. This last metod is basically just assigning the task to do. Hope something of this help..